# SimpleSAMLphp admin page shows using HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, simplesamlphp

When I go here, the SimpleSAMLphp page appears: http://localhost/simplesaml/

When I go here, a 404 "not found" page appears: https://localhost/simplesaml/

httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

    SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR "C:\xampp\simplesamlphp\config"

    Alias /simplesaml C:\xampp\simplesamlphp\www\

    <Directory C:\xampp\simplesamlphp\www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've verified that all other documents are working when accessed via HTTPS; it's only the SimpleSAMLphp admin page that is giving a 404. I have a feeling it has something to do with the alias, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone from the future: try recreating your app in your IdP.

In our case, we recreated our app registration in Azure AD.  We are not sure what the difference is -- as we exactly followed the same steps the second time -- but the issue was resolved.

So, the answer is that SimpleSAMLphp did not have an issue at all; the issue was on the IdP side.